# Can a Web App project and a Cordova Hybrid App project share common code in a single VS2013 solution?

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

Ideally, we'd like to create a single VS2013 solution that contains two projects. One project is a web/browser based version of the application and the other is our hybrid app version that will run on an android tablet. For now, it's a simple app with no dependencies on any cordova plugin. All we have is some JS, HTML and CSS so either target should be viable with the same common code.

We are successful if we make a separate solution/project for each type and pull the related scripts, css, and html from a common repo but this is less than ideal since we still have two distinct solutions/projects for the same shared code.

We've tried using symbolic links in the hybrid project back to the existing items in the web project but these items don't get copied to the hybrid **bld** folder when you build the hybrid app.

If anyone using the VS2013 cordova tools is facing a similar challenge, I'd like to know how you're handling this scenario.